# Google Apps "AdminReports" is not defined.

Tags: google-api

I'm trying to run the sample script from here:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-reports#reference

but it looks like the API isn't enabled / included.

I've enabled the AdminAPI in the Developer Console, have I missed something? I'm able to make calls to UserManager without changing anything, but as this is now depreciated I'd like to use the new API.

Answer (score 2):

Found it. In the script editor, select **Resources > Advanced Google Services**. It needs to be enabled in there as well